# Does COM marshaling work with objects created using CComCoClass::CreateInstance?

Tags: winapi, com, marshalling, atl

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I was wondering if the COM pointer-marshaling functions will work with objects created using ATL's `CComCoClass::CreateInstance`.  According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomcoclass-class?view=msvc-170#createinstance), that method will "create an instance of a COM object and retrieve an interface pointer without using the COM API."  Does that mean its pointer interfaces can't be properly marshaled using COM functions?  Thanks for any info.

Comment: It's been a long time, with @WhozCraig help, Have your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a COM object using `CComCoClass::CreateInstance` the object instance will be created in that apartment where your call is executed. Note that the object will be created in unstable state with reference count equal to zero. You should call `QueryInterface` method for this instance to get the COM interface pointer which can be marshaled to any other apartment.